# Pass variables to Twig Translator

Tags: symfony, twig

In messages.en.yml:

```
variable_name: Welcome to %site_name% - %other_info%
```

In Twig

```
{{ 'variable_name'|trans( -here- ) }}
```

It's the -here- part I'm struggling to know how to pass data in. I must do it this way (above is just an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but if I understand correctly, you only need to give an array as the first parameter of the trans filter.

```
{{ 'variable_name'|trans({'%site_name%': 'My Website'}) }}
```

And of course, values can be variables if you don't put them between quotes :

```
{{ 'variable_name'|trans({'%site_name%': 'My Website', '%other_info%': page_name}) }}
```